# How can I use indexof and substring to extract numbers from a string and make a List<int> of the numbers?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 var file = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\localfile.html");

                int idx = file.IndexOf("something");
                int idx1 = file.IndexOf("</script>", idx);

                string results = file.Substring(idx, idx1 - idx);
```

The result in results is :

```
arrayImageTimes.push('202110071730');arrayImageTimes.push('202110071745');arrayImageTimes.push('202110071800');arrayImageTimes.push('202110071815');arrayImageTimes.push('202110071830');arrayImageTimes.push('202110071845');arrayImageTimes.push('202110071900');arrayImageTimes.push('202110071915');arrayImageTimes.push('202110071930');arrayImageTimes.push('202110071945');
```

I need to extract each number between ' and ' and add each number to a List

For example : to extract the number 202110071730 and add this number to a List

Comment: I would strongly recommend you use a proper tool to parse HTML like [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/). Otherwise I would use regular expressions instead, for example `push\('(\d+)'\)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first split by `;` to get a list of statements.

Then split each statement by `'` to get everything in front of, between and after the `'`. Take the middle one (`[1]`).

```
string s = "arrayImageTimes.push('202110071730');arrayImageTimes.push('202110071745');arrayImageTimes.push('202110071800');arrayImageTimes.push('202110071815');arrayImageTimes.push('202110071830');arrayImageTimes.push('202110071845');arrayImageTimes.push('202110071900');arrayImageTimes.push('202110071915');arrayImageTimes.push('202110071930');arrayImageTimes.push('202110071945');";
var statements = s.Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var statement in statements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(statement.Split('\'')[1]); // add to a list instead
}
```

Or, for all the Regex fanboys, `'(\d+)'` captures a group between `'` with some digits:

```
Regex r= new Regex("'(\\d+)'");
var matches = r.Matches(s);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);  // add to a list instead
}
```

[RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%27%28%5cd%2b%29%27&i=arrayImageTimes.push%28%27202110071730%27%29%3barrayImageTimes.push%28%27202110071745%27%29%3barrayImageTimes.push%28%27202110071800%27%29%3barrayImageTimes.push%28%27202110071815%27%29%3barrayImageTimes.push%28%27202110071830%27%29%3barrayImageTimes.push%28%27202110071845%27%29%3barrayImageTimes.push%28%27202110071900%27%29%3barrayImageTimes.push%28%27202110071915%27%29%3barrayImageTimes.push%28%27202110071930%27%29%3barrayImageTimes.push%28%27202110071945%27%29%3b%0d%0a%0d%0a)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I made a mistake the first time, because I didn't consider the empty element at the end.

Comment: There is a problem in the foreach.  The last item in statements is "\r\n" and that can't be added to the List<string>  I'm getting out of index eception.